# Constructor chaining to print date

Tags: java, localdate, date

How can I print date using constructor chaining in java ? I am getting error after this(6,2018) stating I need two argument constructor why is that? And when i use the quick fix a new constructor Date(int i, int j) is created. I am unable to understand this too.
Here's what I tried -:

```
public class Date
{   
    int dd;
    public Date()
    {
        this(30);
    }

    public Date(int dd)
    {
        this(6,2018);
        this.dd=dd;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Date ob= new Date();
    }

}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are missing a constructor, what you are trying to do is a horrible idea. The design is too rigid. It would be better to model days, monthis and years as separate objects and then use composition to model a date object. Or use [the java time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), because [dates are a pain in the a**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to obtain? Restrictions? Homeowrk? Are you allowed to use standard Java date and time classes like ``java.time``API?

Answer (score 1):

you are attempting to call a constructor with two parameters: this(6,2018); 6 and 2018 which you do not seem to have created.

You need to create a constructor Date(int x, int y){}

Comment: okay, but even when I create a constructor Date(int dd, int yy) the IDE still gives me an error.